# How to use ajax with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, laravel

The following autocomplete codes works.

```
$('#input-personal_name').autocomplete({
    'source': function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('lang.admin.member.members.autocomplete') }}?filter_personal_name=" + encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {        
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['personal_name'],     
                        personal_name: item['personal_name'],   
                        customer_id: item['member_id'],
                        telephone: item['telephone'],
                        mobile: item['mobile'],
                        email: item['email'],
                        payment_company: item['payment_company'],
                        payment_tin: item['payment_tin'],
                        shipping_company: item['shipping_company'],
                        shipping_personal_name: item['shipping_personal_name'],
                        shipping_state_id: item['shipping_state_id'],
                        shipping_city_id: item['shipping_city_id'],
                        shipping_address1: item['shipping_address1'],
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    'select': function(event,ui) {
        $('#input-personal_name').val(event.personal_name);
        $('#input-mobile').val(event.mobile);
        $('#input-telephone').val(event.telephone);
        $('#input-email').val(event.email);
        $('#input-payment_company').val(event.payment_company);
        $('#input-payment_tin').val(event.payment_tin);
        $('#input-shipping_company').val(event.shipping_company);
        $('#input-shipping_personal_name').val(event.shipping_personal_name);
        $('#input-shipping_state_id').val(event.shipping_state_id);
        $('#input-shipping_city_id').val(event.shipping_city_id);
        $('#input-shipping_address1').val(event.shipping_address1);
  }
});
```

Actually, it was only

```
$('#input-email').autocomplete({
    'source': function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=abc&filter_email=' + encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                response($.map(json, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['email'],
                        value: item['customer_id']
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    'select': function (item) {}
});
```

I copied from other project, and spent time to figure out.

But now we want to search not only personal_name, also mobile, telephone, email. So, there are

```
$('#input-mobile').autocomplete({
   ...
});

$('#input-telephone').autocomplete({
   ...
});

$('#input-email').autocomplete({
   ...
});
```

The content of autocomplete are the same, repeated. And it becomes very long. I wish to make it like the following:

```
$('#input-personal_name').autocomplete({
    'source': function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('lang.admin.member.members.autocomplete') }}?filter_personal_name=" + encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {        
                // getMember(json)
                // return getMember(json)
                // return json
                // return item
                // ... ???

            }
        });
    },
    'select': function(event,ui) {
       setMember(event)
  }
});

function getMember(){
    // ???
}

function setMember(event){
    $('#input-personal_name').val(event.personal_name);
    $('#input-mobile').val(event.mobile);
    $('#input-telephone').val(event.telephone);
    $('#input-email').val(event.email);
    $('#input-payment_company').val(event.payment_company);
    $('#input-payment_tin').val(event.payment_tin);
    $('#input-shipping_company').val(event.shipping_company);
    $('#input-shipping_personal_name').val(event.shipping_personal_name);
    $('#input-shipping_state_id').val(event.shipping_state_id);
    $('#input-shipping_city_id').val(event.shipping_city_id);
    $('#input-shipping_address1').val(event.shipping_address1);
}
```

**My problem is, how to get the object from ajax call, then use it inside 'select'?**

Comment: I think you need the appropriate route/filter for each field ! What do you mean by long and repeated ? you expect the same event handling dynamic selectors and dynamic route filters... That could be possible if they have the exact same code pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one night dreaming, I got the answer.

**MemberController.php**

```
public function autocomplete()
{
    $json = [];

    if(isset($this->request->filter_personal_name) && mb_strlen($this->request->filter_personal_name, 'utf-8') > 0)
    {
        $filter_data['filter_personal_name'] = $this->request->filter_personal_name;
    }

    if(isset($this->request->filter_mobile) && strlen($this->request->filter_mobile) > 3)
    {
        $filter_data['filter_mobile'] = $this->request->filter_mobile;
    }

    if(isset($this->request->filter_telephone) && strlen($this->request->filter_telephone) > 1)
    {
        $filter_data['filter_telephone'] = $this->request->filter_telephone;
    }

    if(isset($this->request->filter_email) && strlen($this->request->filter_email) > 1)
    {
        $filter_data['filter_email'] = $this->request->filter_email;
    }

    $rows = $this->memberService->getRows($filter_data)->toArray();

    foreach ($rows as $key =>$row) {
        $row['label'] = $row['personal_name'];
        $row['customer_id'] = $row['id'];
        $json[] = $row;
    }

    return response(json_encode($json))->header('Content-Type','application/json');
}
```

**order_form.blade.php**

```
<input type="text" id="input-personal_name" name="personal_name" value="{{ $order->personal_name }}" list="list-personal_name" >
<datalist id="list-personal_name"></datalist>

<input type="text" id="input-mobile" name="mobile" value="{{ $order->mobile}}" list="list-mobile" >
<datalist id="list-mobile"></datalist>

<input type="text" id="input-telephone" name="telephone" value="{{ $order->telephone}}" list="list-telephone" >
<datalist id="list-telephone"></datalist>

<input type="text" id="input-email" name="email" value="{{ $order->email}}" list="list-email" >
<datalist id="list-email"></datalist>
．．．
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function setOrder(item)
{
  $('#input-personal_name').val(item.personal_name);
  $('#input-customer_id').val(item.customer_id);
  $('#input-telephone').val(item.telephone);
  $('#input-mobile').val(item.mobile);
  $('#input-email').val(item.email);
  $('#input-payment_company').val(item.payment_company);
  $('#input-payment_tin').val(item.payment_tin);  
  $('#input-shipping_company').val(item.shipping_company);
  $('#input-shipping_personal_name').val(item.shipping_personal_name);
  $("#input-shipping_address1").val(item.shipping_address1);
  $("#input-shipping_city_id").val(item.shipping_city_id);
  $("#input-shipping_state_id").val(item.shipping_state_id);
}

$('#input-personal_name').autocomplete({
    'source': function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('lang.admin.member.members.autocomplete') }}?filter_personal_name=" + encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {        
                response(json);
            }
        });
    },
    'select': function(event,ui) {
        setOrder(event)
  }
});

$('#input-mobile').autocomplete({
    ... //same code with personal_name
});

$('#input-telephone').autocomplete({
    ... //same code with personal_name
});

$('#input-email').autocomplete({
    ... //same code with personal_name
});

--></script>
```

1. All example codes on internet has "label" and "value" inside
   autocomplete 'source', but only label is needed.
2. Since label is needed, we make it, in controller's foreach
3. Then we use response(json) directly, no need to map().